# build table from select/union

Tags: mysql, sql, select, union

i've a relationa table build from a csv file that contains, external keys on each row.

table structure:

```
| id | tree/nome | tree/regioni/0 | .... | tree/regioni/n
```

"n" is equal to 36!!!
I have build a table "regions" from a "SELECT/DINSTICT" and I added an id on it;

now I need to build another table to extrat the "external keys" "tree/regioni/n" with the "id" of each row.

The NOT smart way that ive found to achieve this is to build the table from a SELECT/UNION of each 'tree/regioni/n':

```
SELECT `id`,`tree/regioni/0`
FROM `trees` WHERE 1 
UNION 
SELECT `id`,`tree/regioni/1`
FROM `trees` WHERE 1  
[.....]
UNION 
SELECT `id`,`tree/regioni/N`
FROM `trees` 
WHERE 1
```

Comment: Off the top of my head, you might not be using optimal table design here.  If the `n` values were in a single column, but spread out across different records, you could just restrict using a simple `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Yeah, this is the standard way to do an unpivot operation in mysql. What's the problem with the union query?

Answer (score 0):

Your method is fine.  If `trees` where a view, then you would have the problem of evaluating the view multiple times.  Even with a table, you have to scan the table multiple times.

Assuming you do not have duplicates that you want removed, change `union` to `union all`.  You can also use a `cross join`:

```
select t.id,
       (case when n = 1 then `tree/regioni/0`
             when n = 2 then `tree/regioni/1`
             . . .
        end)
from t cross join
     (select 0 as n union all
      select 1 as n union all
      . . .
     ) x;
```

This looks more complicated but it only scans/evaluates the table expressions once.